# Retrieve source code at runtime

Tags: java

I wish to print java code to console at runtime. I am not expecting exactly the same code, but the logic to be there.

Given the following:

`Predicate<String> predicate = (s) -> s.equals("yes");`

I would like to call:

`String javaCode = getCodeString(predicate);`

And have `javaCode` logically equal to: `(s) -> s.equals(\"yes\")")`.

Is this possible?

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: Java is compiled to bytecode, so the closest you could come is maybe reading that somehow...

Comment: may be using java "reflection"... you could find something.. =(

Answer (score 0):

Not easily. Even if you had the source code available to your application, you couldn't do it in the context described. Theoretically it would be possible to have the source code available (or embedded in the JAR). Then theoretically if you knew the line number you could get the source code. However, to know the line number you have to throw an exception. Using lambdas would make this even more complicated. If you want to start reading byte code, you might be able to do something similar, but what you asking is very complicated.